# Does allocation unit size or block size correlate to memory card speed?

Tags: windows, ssd, format

[image]

I have microSDXC cards that I want to use as a storage drive and as a drive used for capturing 4k drone footage. It starts to perform the best on average between reads and writes at 256kB transfer sizes and above. When I'm formatting the card should I set the allocation unit size to at least 256kB and exFat? Would setting it to something like 4kB cripple it based on its low performance at the size?

Comment: *"It starts to perform the best at 256kB transfer sizes"* -- No, it does not; you're only considering writes and ignoring reads.  IMO 16KB block size looks like an optimum size.  You only give up 22% of the best write rate, but get the 2nd-best read rate and not an outlandish block size.  Use large allocation size when storing large files such as photos and videos.

Comment: So yes, allocation unit size does correlate to memory card performance?

Comment: I think not. Regardless to allocation unit size, copying large files result in large bulk reads and writes. As an indirect evidence, HDDs have crippled 4KB random read/write speeds, yet NTFS uses 4KB allocation units uniformly on them. Larger allocation unit size results in smaller FATs, corresponding memory savings, and possibly faster space allocations - but negligible on current devices. It's more a legacy from 20st century than something modern users should care.

Comment: Cluster size also influences how much overhead is needed for operations. If your NTFS is using 4KB clusters and your HDD is using 512 Byte sectors you still need to read four individual sectors to read the whole cluster.  Bigger clusters also result in bigger waste. If you have 1 MB clusters a 1 byte text file still requires the allocation/reservation of a whole MB. As @sawdust pointed out the reads are also important depending on your actual needs. Running a DB to log performance data is way different photo editing.